# How can I get the equivalent from LaTeX command \overline{BC} using typst?

Tags: typst

I want to note a segment between two points, B and C. Using Latex, I can get it by `$\overline{BC}$`. In [typst app](https://typst.app/), I don't know how to do it.

The best approximation in typst is $overline("BC")$ *but* the points *B* and *C* are now in upright font, naturally. I need them to be in an italic font like this: *BC*

Using `$overline("_BC_")` does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typst interprets `$BC$` as a function (or variable) called "BC". Only [single characters](https://typst.app/docs/reference/math) are interpreted as text. This means you can use: `$overline(B C)$`.

You can also explicitly state that you want [italics](https://typst.app/docs/reference/math/styles): `$overline(italic("BC"))$`